# How to use CSS to split dynamic components?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, css-selectors, grid

how can I use CSS to make this division of photos in a dynamic component?

[image]

The first item should always be full and the rest in the area below, if you have 2 or 3 photos, divide the space correctly

I'm trying to do this with grid components, like:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
```

and combining with
`&:first-of-type`

But I'm not having success with it

Another example with the same component:

[image]

- I can use styled component to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic example using flexbox, if you don't know the number of elements:

```css
html,
body,
section {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem 1rem 4rem;
}

article {
  flex: 1 1 1px;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: plum;
}

article:first-child {
  flex: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
</section>
<section>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
</section>
<section>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
</section>
```

Here's a simpler example for 3 elements where you can `grid-column: span 2` the `:first-child`:

```css
html,
body,
section {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

article {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: plum;
}

article:first-child {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
</section>
```

You can adapt it for 4 elements:

```css
html,
body,
section {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

article {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: plum;
}

article:first-child {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
</section>
```